# MVC From posting for multiple items

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am passing a list of company object from a controller to the view using the following code:

**Controller**

```
          var res = new WebReference.CompaniesCollection();
            try
            {
                WebReference.CareWebService cl = new WebReference.CareWebService();

                res = cl.getCompanies("P@ssw0rd");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            return View(res.Companies);
```

### View

```
            @model IEnumerable<TestLink.WebReference.Company>

            @{
                ViewBag.Title = "Companies";
            }
```

I want to write here the code to display company name and select button beside each and then click call a form post method in the controller to process that company. How can I achieve that? I don't want the id to appear when form is posted in the URL.

The company object has the following properties:

- company_id (int)
- company_name (string)
- company_address (string)

Comment: What all you tried? formcollection? or with use of hidden fields etc?